# Dual operator space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $E$ is an operator space and $E^*$ is the dual operator space. It is well known that the matricial norm structure on $E^*$ is given by the formula $\|[f_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n\|_{M_n(E^*)}:=\sup\{\|f_{ij}(v_{kl})\|:\|v\|_{M_n(E)}\leq 1\}.$ Is it true that if $[f_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$  is just a column matrix, then the supremum can be taken on the set where $v$ is a column matrix with norm $\leq 1$?

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum

Comment: @Gerald. Can you please elaborate what's wrong?

Comment: If you read the information about mathovervflow you can find this: "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer mathematical questions related to current research in mathematics."

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I don't immediately see why either this topic or this question are not MO-worthy

Comment: @ Gerald. Please explain your comment further. I want to know your viewpoint more clearly. Tell me precisely your objections.

Comment: I agree with @YemonChoi.  That said, the question is not very well written: if we are meant to be considering a _column vector_ then why write $[f_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$ with both $i$ and $j$ varying from $1$ to $n$?  That's a matrix, not a column vector...  Also, what evidence do you have for your conjecture: could you provide an example (non-trivial) Operator Space where it's true?

Comment: @Matthew. I was trying some research problem in operator spaces. According to my other evidences this might be true. One more intuition comes from the fact that if we have a linear map $\phi:E\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ then $\|\phi\|_{cb}=\|\phi_n\|.$ This somehow indicates that to calculate the cb norm of $\phi$ it is alright to take a sup over smaller set!!

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician In the definition, the supremum is taken over $v$ AND $i,j$? could you please explain this and mention where you have seen this definition?